# Continuous function on $[0,1]$ with a condition.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous map such that $f(x)=f(x^{3})$ for all $x$. Then we have to find the value of $f(1)-f(0)$. How to find it?

Comment: Could the downvoters give a comment?

Comment: You are commenting on your own question YOGESH, I deleted my answer a while ago.

Comment: yes but you calculated as f(x)=x^3

Comment: I am aware of that, which is why I deleted it a while ago. If you read carefully J,E Pin is not the same as Gamamal.

Comment: please explane it

Comment: This question has now three close votes for the reason *This question does not appear to be about math within the scope defined in the help center.* Could anybody tell me why this question is not about math within the scope defined in the help center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in (0,1)$ be any number. Then consider the sequence $(x,x^3,x^6,\ldots)$. Clearly, this sequence converges to $0$ so by continuity of $f$ the sequence $(f(x^{3n}))$ will converge to $f(0)$ but since $(f(x^{3n}))$ is a constant sequence by hypothesis, it follows that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$ and hence by continuity at $1$ it also follows that $f$ has to be a constant function. Hence $f(1)-f(0)= 0$.

Comment: While it is ultimately true, you do *not* get $f(x)=f(x^{3n})$ for all natural $n$ without using continuity

Answer (score 2):

$f$ must be constant. Indeed, for $x_0\in (0,1)$, the sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=x_n^3$ converges to $0$, hence $f(x_0)=f(x_1)=\ldots$ and by continuity at $0$ finally $f(x_0)=f(0)$. Hence $f$ is constant on $[0,1)$ and by continuity on all of $[0,1]$. Consequently $$f(1)-f(0)=0.$$

Comment: yes i got it thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. You know that $f(x) = f(x^3)$. From this it also follows that $f(x) = f(x^9)$. Inductively you get that $f(x) = f(x^{3^n})$ for all natural $n$. For $x\in(0,1)$, what does $x^{3^n}$ tend to? Do you see how this answers your question? (Note: continuity is very important here.)

Comment: I disagree. You can't say that $f(0)$ equals that stuff, but the induction is fine. You could concoct an example where the function satisfies the property for all $n$ and $x$ but isn't continuous. It won't be an easy thing to write down but it could be done.